# 404 error, Zend Framework 2 The requested URL could not be matched by routing

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm getting:

> **A 404 error occurred**
>
> Page not found. The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

My `module.config.php` file is:

```
'router' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'Test' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                //http://localhost/Test/Test
                'route' => '/Test[/[:action]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
             ),
             'defaults' => array(
                 'controller' => 'Test\Controller\Test',
                 'action' => 'Test'
              ),
          ),
      ),
   ),
),
```

help please, i am new in Zend Framework 2 !

Answer (score 3):

You should use configuration like Application module in ZendSkeletonApplication:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'test' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/book',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Test\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Test',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

You just add the following code:

```
'test' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '[/:action][/:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'     => '[0-9]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Test\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Test',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

add this code to 'child-routes' key and after that you'll access to url: localhost/:controller_name/:action_name/:id (example : http://zf.dev/test/index or http://zf.dev/test/add/1). And now it's work!
This code can fix error 404 for tutorial in zf2 documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo, try this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
```

Routes rather than router twice..

Comment: thanks, for you answer friend, i add routes and :                              Fatal error: Class 'Test\Controller\TestController' not found in D:\wamp\www\zf\web\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 17

Comment: Have you made an invokable for your controller?:
'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Test'          => 'Test\Controller\TestController',

Comment: You also need to make sure your controller actually exists :)

Comment: yes, i have: return array(
        'controllers' => array(
                'invokables' => array(
                        'Test\Controller\Test' => 'Test\Controller\TestController'
                ),        
        ),

Comment: can you post some controller code? Have you got the namespace correct inside the controller class?

Comment: hello andrew, my controller code: <?php

namespace Test\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class TestController extends AbstractActionController
{
 public function TestAction()
 {
  
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

Achieve fix it, I was missing the letter "d", was thus: Zend \ Loader \ StandarAutoloader I added the "d": Zend \ Loader \ StandardAutoloader. Greetings Friends. TIP: Zend Studio 10 and his version de ZF2 run perfect for this moment !

Answer (score 0):

Please check the .htaccess file and index.php files. If these are exist in public folder means, you have to use the url as

```
 http://localhost/public/Test/Test.
```

Your codes are almost right. Andrew has guided you well. Let me know your response.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i have this in my .htacces   :   RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

Comment: Have you included the Module name in application.config.php file. 'modules' => array(
        'Test',
    ),

Comment: hi, user2003356 i have this in my application.config.php  file <?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Test'
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);

Comment: Please call this url. http://localhost/test/test. Convert uppercase characters to lowercase. And please update, where do you placed the htaccess file.

Comment: i test this http://localhost/Test/Test and :  Not Found

The requested URL /Test/Test was not found on this server.  ,  my .htacces file is in the public folder of my Zend Framework ,

Comment: No. Please understand Juan. I asked to call this url. localhost/test/test. Please change the UPPERCASE T to LOWERCASE t.

Comment: ok, i change the UPPERCASE T to LOWERCASE t  and : Not Found

The requested URL /test/test was not found on this server.

Comment: Check the Application module codes from top to bottom. So that you can fix.

Comment: :c, i have this:  <?php

namespace Test;

class Module
{
 public function getConfig()
 {
  return include __DIR__ .'/config/module.config.php';
 }
 
 public function ClassAutoloaderConfig()
 {
  return array(
   'Zend\Loader\StandarAutoloader' => array(
           'namespaces' => array(
                      __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                 ),
             ),
        );
    }
}

Comment: can you able to run application module in your server?

Comment: i am new in ZF2 and do not know if I'm missing something to run modules frankly, I use Zend Studio 10 and I created a new project Zend Framework Project, my zend studio 10 comes with ZF 2.1.0.

Comment: please download ZF2's sample application - skeleton album application. It helps you to know ZF2 workflow. Please do it. I'll help you.

Comment: oks'll see that and anything I write again in this post, friend, thanks for the help today.

Answer (score 0):

1.You should check also `application.config.php`
and add your module name into RETURN array.

```
return array(    
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'your_module',
        .....    
 ),
```

2.If Doesn't.Check route array in `module.config.php`

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest also check the data folder that has cached config files, config files being cached in dev install also may cause this issue. 
delete files inside data/cache and try.

PS: if you are just starting try with blog module on zend site it is for beginners and more updated with new versions.

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/first-module.html